# How to map only the GSI using DynamoDBEnhancedClient in Java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I have a table in DynamoDb like this:

```
{
   "partitionKey": ...
   "sortKey": ...
   "fieldOne": ...
   "fieldTwo": ...
   "fieldThree": ...
}
```

I added a global secondary index in my CDK like this:

```js
private createTable(): Table {
    const fieldOneGsi: GlobalSecondaryIndexProps = {
        indexName: 'fieldOneGsi',
        partitionKey:{
            name: 'partitionKey',
            type: AttributeType.STRING
        },
        sortKey: {
            name: 'fieldOne',
            type: AttributeType.STRING
        },
        projectionType: ProjectionType.INCLUDE,
        nonKeyAttributes: ['fieldTwo']
    }
    table.addGlobalSecondaryIndex(fieldOneGsi);
}
```

Since my GSI will only return 3 attributes: `partition_key`, `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo`. Can I only map the table schema for these attributes for querying using [`DynamoDbEnhancedClient`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/example_dynamodb_Query_section.html)? For example, something like in Java:

```java
@DynamoDbBean
public class MyTable {
    
    private String partitionKey;
    private String fieldOne;
    private String fieldTwo;

    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    @DynamoDbSecondaryPartitionKey(indexNames = {"fieldOneGsi"})
    @DynamoDbAttribute("partition_key")
    public String getPartitionKey(){
        return partitionKey;
    }

    @DynamoDbSecondarySortKey(indexNames = {"fieldOneGsi"})
    @DynamoDbAttribute("fieldOne")
    public String getFieldOne(){
        return fieldOne;
    }

    @DynamoDbAttribute("fieldTwo")
    public String getFieldTwo(){
        return fieldTwo;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try this? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

This should work with no issue, however you're forgetting one aspect, DynamoDB always propagates the base table keys, no matter what you choose to project. For that reason, be sure to have getters/setters for your base table keys also.

Comment: so you're saying include my `sort_key` or just add the setters for the attributes above? for setters, I'm using Lombok (which i omitted) to auto generate

Comment: I'm not sure what your base table keys are, but you will need to map both it's partition and sort key to parse an item correctly.